# Access violation, NotEnemy is 0xBF800000

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d

I use cocos2d-x to do the game. After running my program for a while, the variable "NotEnemy" will always report the "access violation" error. NotEnemy is the variable I set in EventListenerPhysicsContact, always using cocos2d-x There will be errors like the title, all I want to know when there is such a mistake, is there any solution, I hope someone can tell me, right, NotEnemy I am assigned this way, auto NotEnemy=contact.getShapeB( )->getBody()->getNode();

Comment: you could show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting it to nullptr after using NotEnemy, but it didn't work. Now it generates a new error "Exception at 0x76EE35D2 (located in TankBattle.exe): Microsoft C++ Exception: std::exception, in memory Location 0x00C5F548.
There is an unhandled exception at 0x7640E6EB (ucrtbase.dll) (in TankBattle.exe): A critical program exit has been requested. ", used to be an error about access permissions conflicts, but they are all problems with NotEnemy, and they all appear in the "NotEnemy->SetPosition(Vec2(166,14))" statement.